# Do I need a Transit Visa of Canada if I have F1 and SX1 Visas?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas, f1-visas

I have a flight reservation from Austin, Texas to New Delhi, India. The flight transits through Toronto. I have a valid F1 and SX1 Visa. Do I need transit visa to transit through Canada? My layover is less than 5 hours and I won't be leaving the airport. My SX1 visa is active till 2027 and is valid for multiple entries. Will I be needing a transit Visa?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: Yes, you need a visa to change planes in Toronto

Long Answer: If an airline passenger is refused entry at a transit point or destination, the airline is required to return the passenger to the point of departure at the airline's expense (although they may try to recover the cost from the passenger). Thus, airlines are very careful to determine what documents are required by a particular passenger's travel before allowing that passenger to board. Airlines use the IATA database [Timatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) to reveal what documents are required.

Putting your information into Timatic through [this online portal](https://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) (there are others), generates this:

> National India (IN)             /Transit Canada (CA)
>   Destination India (IN)
>   ...
>
> Passport required
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for the intended transit period.
>
> Visa required.

Thus, you will require a Canadian visa and your Indian passport to transit in Toronto.